# 25 Color gradations from every Color

Tags: vb.net, algorithm, colors, transformation

in my program the user can choose a color and then i have to generate 25 gradations from that color. Is there any function to use or does sb has an idea how to do that? The first Color has to be white and the 25th color really dark.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

**The easy way:**

I assume the color is known in RGB format.

So simply multiply each value of R, G, B with a factor to change the brightness.

*Example:*
if you have R=12, G=40, B=128

you can multiply each by 0.5 => R=6, G=20, B=64 to get a darker version of the color.

**The more complex way:**

Transform your color in an other color space which has a separate component for *lightness*  e.g. [Lab color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space). Ther you can simply change the *lightness* and than transform the result back to RGB (if needed).

Comment: The easy way doesnt work i think, because you dont know which figure you need to multiply with. Every color need a different figure.

Comment: @mantaplatte: Maybe you're right. But the general idea should work. Also how to handle 0 values needs some more thought.

Answer (score 0):

Use an appropriate color space. HSV/HSL use a saturation component that cna realizes exactly what you want. As other answer suggest, CIELab is now considered as more appropriate than older HSV/HSL.